# May I replace ICR 18650 22F with 26H in Laptop battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, laptop, lithium-polymer

As in the title, I have a worn laptop battery, made out of 6x SAMSUNG ICR 18650 22F. Now I can't find any 22F near me, nor slightly farther for a sane price. But SAMSUNG ICR 18650 26H are practically swamping me from all sides.

I checked the basic specifications and all seems in order apart from one. My main worries are:

1. Are 26H only far cheaper because 22F are out of production (or low priority production) and hence out of stock price difference. Or is there a reason for the 50-100% price difference?
2. Will the chargers, controller, and computer register the battery correctly if it now has 2,6Ah per cell instead of 2,2Ah?

I mean, I can get 26H with tabs already on them for still cheaper than ordering 22F (if i don't even count postage to 22F's price)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's hard to tell if it will be a problem.
Protection circuits will not mind the capacity difference. Safe voltages remain the same. But since you say it's for a laptop battery, there will be a gas gauge somewhere (probably also in the battery). Depending what type it is and how it's programmed, this gas gauge might not be able to cope with the larger capacity, i.e. report unreliable charge states.

Comment: From that Answer, I guess better play it safe I guess. I mean its still about 6 times cheaper than buying HP replacement battery pack.
I'm just a bit sad about the soldering tabs. Any Or if you know of any credible shop that sells them with soldering tabs already on them. Not a fan of doing that job myself, don't find contact welding all that fun.

PS: You get the answer unless someone comes with a full sheet of details and differences.